# HTML table span entire width

Tags: html, html-table

Consider:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" ID="Table2">
    <tr>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This code still leaves an "inch" of space on both sides of the table. I am trying to get the table to span the entire width of the page.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try (in your <head> section, or existing CSS definitions)...

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 18):

There might be a margin style that your table is inheriting.  Try setting the margin of the table to 0:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" ID="Table2" style="margin: 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also it could be the width or margin of the parent element(s), all the way up to body/

Comment: Is this the best way to over ride what is in the CSS?

Answer (score 7):

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
```

works for me.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the margin of the body to 0 for the table to stretch the full width. Alternatively, you can set the margin of the table to a negative number as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI:

*html* should be *table* and  `width: 100%`.

*span* should be `margin: auto;`.

Comment: What do you mean by *"html should be table"*? Can you elaborate? Preferably by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35944342/edit). But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score -2):

*Just in case* you're using [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/), you can add `px-0` (set left/right padding to 0) and `mx-0` (set left/right margin to 0) CSS class to the *body* tag, like below:

```
<body class="px-0; mx-0">
    <!--your body HTML-->
</body>
```