# HTML Table fill to edge of screen

Tags: html-table, width, html, fill

What I am trying to do is get the grey boxes on [this](http://aesdigital.co.uk/English/test) to go to the edge of the page, I have found a similar article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539309/html-table-span-entire-width) but when I have tried changing the margin and padding to 0 nothing is happening, this table is created in a cms that has been coded by previous developers and I have no idea why I can't get these grey areas to automatically fill the edge of any size screen.

Any help on where I am going wrong would be grateful as I am re-developing this website and need it done ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you will have to remove the width of the wrapper to auto
2. then add to your **content2** div something like: **padding: 0 200px;** for the gray only

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `#wrapper` style is set to `width: 970px`. Change that to `width: auto` and you're good to go.

Comment: Yes that fills the page but would I need it to do is keep the text in the same place and only extend the background across

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about the box shown in blue below

is because the table is been redered inside the `<div id="wrapper">`

if you change the  width: of the DIV to auto....  your boxes will go all the way to the edge as shown on the other image

[image: image of link for example]

**after changing the width to auto of the wrapper div looks like:**

[image]